# Selenium - wait for page to render dynamic page

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, selenium, web

I have a Dynamic web page that refreshes and loads new data. I am using Selenium and I need to wait till the page has finished rendering before I can continue checking the page. I have seen many posts about waiting for the page to load or using explicit waits (implicit wait could solve the problem but is very unelegant and not fast enough). The problem with using explicit waits is not having any info on what will come up after the refresh. I have seen some solutions talking about waiting for all the connections to the server to end but that will not promise me that the actual UI has finished rendering.

What I need is a way to know if a page has finished to render (not load!!)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you DO KNOW what sctructure will come after the page will load. You don't know what tags were not on the page, but you know what DOM will look like. That's why usually it's worst practice to test with page text, but a good one to have a website tested by DOM only. So, depending on what structure appears on the page you will need to have explicit ways waiting for specific tags will appear on the page.
One more solution (but as I told it's not really the best practice) is to wait for `document.readystate` is "complete". This state will not help in every situation, but if you have something still loading on the page, in more then half cases it will not return complete. So, you should have some kind of implicit state that is executing:

```
string readyState = javascript.ExecuteScript("if (document.readyState) return document.readyState;").ToString();
```

and then checking:

```
readyState.ToLower() == "complete";
```

btw if you will use protractor as an angular js application test executor, it's waiting for angular page loaded by default, or in some difficult situations you can use:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

OR do something in a callback

```
button.click().then(function() {
  // go next step
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem with the product I am testing. I had to create special functions for click,click_checkbox,sendKeys and getText for example. These include try catch methods for cathcing NoSuchElement StaleElementReference exceptions. Also it retries if the actions fail, like sending the wrong text.

```
document.readyState
```

This isnt enough for you. It only waits for the DOM to load. WHen the HTML tag are loaded, it returns "complete". So you have to wait for each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me well with dynamically rendered websites - I do not have a time constraint in getting the data as it would run in background for me, if efficiency is an issue may be this is not the solution for you (50s is a huge time for any website to load after the ready state is completed) :

1. Wait for complete page to load

```html
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50); 
wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd -> ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

2. Make another implicit wait with a dummy condition which would always fail

```html
  try {          
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + "This text will always fail :)" + "')]"))); // condition you are certain won't be true 
  } 
  catch (TimeoutException te) {
  }
```

3. Finally, instead of getting the html source - which would in most of one page applications would give you a different result , pull the outerhtml of the first html tag

```html
String script = "return document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\")[0].outerHTML;"; 
content = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script).toString();
```